# Unable to create a AWS Cognito User Pool user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to create a user using the **Cognito User Pool Console** (I'm setting values for the username and the temporary password) but I keep getting this error.

> Attributes did not conform to the schema: birthdate: Number must be no longer than 10 characters (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: 98f3de9e-5ce3-11e7-98e8-9d0c69d31df9)

The **User Pool** is created with the following using serverless

```
Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
  DeletionPolicy: Retain
  Properties:
    UserPoolName: employees
    AdminCreateUserConfig:
      AllowAdminCreateUserOnly: true
    Policies:
      PasswordPolicy:
        MinimumLength: 8
        RequireLowercase: true
        RequireNumbers: true
    Schema:
      - Name: "picture"
        AttributeDataType: String
        Mutable: true
        Required: false
      - Name: "given_name"
        AttributeDataType: String
        Mutable: true
        Required: true
      - Name: "middle_name"
        AttributeDataType: String
        Mutable: true
        Required: false
      - Name: "family_name"
        AttributeDataType: String
        Mutable: true
        Required: true
      - Name: "address"
        AttributeDataType: String
        Mutable: true
        Required: false
      - Name: "birthdate"
        AttributeDataType: String
        Mutable: true
        Required: true
      - Name: "gender"
        AttributeDataType: String
        Mutable: true
        Required: true
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be quite late but try below code, I defined the MinLength and MaxLength:

```
Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
  DeletionPolicy: Retain
  Properties:
    UserPoolName: employees
    AdminCreateUserConfig:
      AllowAdminCreateUserOnly: true
    Policies:
      PasswordPolicy:
        MinimumLength: 8
        RequireLowercase: true
        RequireNumbers: true
    Schema:
      - Name: "picture"
        AttributeDataType: String
        Mutable: true
        Required: false
      - Name: "given_name"
        AttributeDataType: String
        Mutable: true
        Required: true
      - Name: "middle_name"
        AttributeDataType: String
        Mutable: true
        Required: false
      - Name: "family_name"
        AttributeDataType: String
        Mutable: true
        Required: true
      - Name: "address"
        AttributeDataType: String
        Mutable: true
        Required: false
      - Name: "birthdate"
        AttributeDataType: String
        Mutable: true
        Required: true
        DeveloperOnlyAttribute: false
        StringAttributeConstraints: 
          MinLength: "10"
          MaxLength: "10"
      - Name: "gender"
        AttributeDataType: String
        Mutable: true
        Required: true
```